# Xml serialization/deserialization in WinRT (Store application)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, c++-cx

I need to make a Windows Store application that exchanges xml serialized data over a TCP connection with a server. Since I need to use Direct3D rendering in the application I went for the c++/cx store application template however I ran into issues with xml serialization/deserialization.

My usual approach in C# would be to use the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and classes with [DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) annotations. However as soon as I try to import `System.Xml.Serialization` assembly I get the `C1114` error - `WinRT does not support #using of a managed assembly`. However there are lots of examples that mention using this approach in a Windows Phone app from C#.

So the question is - is only c++/cx limited in support for .NET in Windows Store applications and C# can use all the standard components on phone as well or is switching to C# in this case also not a solution and I need to use the WinRT classes for xml serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable, what with the variety of frameworks Microsoft has put out there.

C++/Cx is a **native** binding to the Windows Runtime (WinRT). It does not use any managed code or the .NET framework in any way, which is why you're getting the C1114 error.

C# provides a managed binding to WinRT. It does leverage the .NET framework, so in a C# Windows Store application, you can make use of some of the base-class library. This subset is referred to as the .NET Profile. This article talks about this more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/04/17/net-for-metro-style-apps.aspx

In your specific case, you are using a C++/Cx application because you want access to Direct3D. This makes sense, although it means that you will not have access to System.Xml.Serialization. Instead, as you surmised, you will need to use APIs that are available to C++/Cx to read XML, specifically Windows.Data.Xml.Dom: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.aspx

Comment: Thanks for providing the links, I'll try switching to Qt:)